# Cant change owner of new file

Tags: php, apache, fopen, file-ownership

I'm using PHP to retrieve some Base64 data, decode it and write it to a file, my code works fine. However, the owner is apache and the permissions are very low, so even if I FTP into the area where it's uploaded, i cannot download the file. However do i change the permission and owner so i have more control over the file? Here is my code

```
$path = "uploads/";
$filename = time().".png";
$full_path = $path.$filename;

$image_encoded = $_POST['image'];
$image_decoded = base64_decode($image_encoded);

$handle = fopen($full_path, 'x+');
fwrite($handle, $image_decoded);
fclose($handle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The superuser and the files' **owner** can change the owner with:
 [`chown ( string $filename , mixed $user )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php)

The files' **permissions** can be changed using:
 [`chmod ( string $filename , int $mode )`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php)

Plese note you need to use octal notation for the files' permissions, *string notation as in Unix won't work!* To grant the files' owner every permission, and to allow the other users to be able to read (download) it, the permisison in octal notation is: `0744`

[See Wikipedia for more information about the octal notation of file permissions.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions#Octal_notation)

Comment: All chown, chmod and chgrp (for the group) fail to do anything.

Comment: Actually, I'm wrong. Use 0755 instead of 755 worked in the chmod function.

Comment: For these functions to work, you need to be *superuser or owner of the file*. So, the user creating the file and the user changing the permissions need to be the same. Normally, both are `php`. If this isn't the case for you, something in your Apache configuration is probably broken.

Comment: Please also read the second last paragraph in my answer, about the octal notation! Also, if you don't need to execute the file (as in your case), `0744` should be enough permissions!

Answer (score 1):

you might want to use chmod to change file permissions.

Perhaps you are not entitled to download it... You may change it's permissions to 755 or something...

```
chmod($full_path, 0755);
$handle = fopen($full_path, 'x+');
//...
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

You should be able to change it's permissions because the file was created by php(the owner)...

Comment: Actually, the owner is Apache, not PHP.

Comment: This doesn't work. The `x+` in fopen is creating the file because it doesn't exist.